# vi opens Vim, but vim is not found

Tags: vim

When I type `vim` to open Vim, it says the command is not found. Then I try `vi`. This opens Vim. *(I don't find a problem with that, but it just shows that Vim **is** installed.)*

Why? If Vim is installed why doesn't `vim` open it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You most likely have the package `vim-tiny` installed which can be executed with the commands `vi` or `vim.tiny` as shown in the package description. Also you probably have pre-installed the package `vim-common` (it has some configuration files according to the description) which may be shown as Vim in the ubuntu software center. There is a separate package `vim` which can be installed with the command `sudo apt-get install vim`. There are not many differences between vim and vim-tiny (which has a smaller subset of features).

Comment: This may be what's happening. I'll try `vim.tiny` tonight and see if that opens Vim. Also I didn't notice anything saying tiny on the splash screen, but I'm not positive I didn't not.

Comment: @CaptainMan Both `vi` and `vim.tiny` commands will open the same program and yes it will be shown as Vim, but it really is vim.tiny. To verify it you can open your file manager and see that /usr/bin/vi is a link for /etc/alternatives/vi which is a link for /usr/bin/vim.tiny. Or run the command `update-alternatives --get-selections`. If you want to use the full vim with all the features, then install the package `vim` and use it with the `vim` command (or make it default for the `vi` command by executing `sudo update-alternatives --config vi`).